# When i publish my website on asp.net the signup/log in stops working

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, visual-studio, connection-string

I have been working on a project using the database I have on my laptop
and I did a signup / log in page and when I press start without debugging it works fine and the data gets stored in the database
but we are required to upload our website to the host by publishing it and when I do that
the sign up / log in stops working
I uploaded my database to smarter asp and I used the connection string but it still won't work
and it doesn't show me any errors either

this is the sign up code

```
  public partial class trainerSignup : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    string strcon = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["db_a75920_982coursesConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strcon);
            if (con.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            {
                con.Open();
            }
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(@"insert into trainerSignup(trainerUsername,password,confirmPassword,email)
                                             values(@trainerUsername,@password,@confirmPassword,@email)", con);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@trainerUsername", TextBox1.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", TextBox2.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmPassword", TextBox3.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", TextBox4.Text.Trim());
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@account_status", "pending");

            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            con.Close();
            Response.Write("<script>alert('Sign Up Successful. Go to Trainer Login to Login');</script>");

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Response.Write("<script>alert('" + ex.Message + "');</script>");
        }
    }
}
```

}

and this is the web.config

```
   <add name="db_a75920_982coursesConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source=SQL5085.site4now.net;Initial Catalog=db_a75920_courses982;User Id=db_a75920_courses982_admin;Password=xxxxxx"
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
```

can anyone help me?

Comment: This code probably passes in the catch block on the production server. But if ex.Message contains a single quote, it will produce a JavaScript error and the message won’t be shown. Please add a Litteral in the markup and change your catch block: myLitteral.Text = ex.Message;

Comment: Unable to connect to SQL access permissions. If possible, enter the received error in the your questions.

Comment: @Rahaf, what is the **smarter asp** you mentioned in the question?

Comment: @Rahaf what is the error message that you see? Please make sure you double check your connection string again.

Answer (score 0):

in connection string password is xxxxxx replace xxxxxx value with your actual password. and try to debug with live sql connection in your laptop.

Comment: hello yes i just put xxxx because i was going to post the question here but in the actual code it is my actual password